# Can I create a hash value from a field that is nvarchar(max)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, hash

Is it possible to create a hash value from a field that is NVARCHAR(Max) in SQL, and how?

For example:

```
SELECT Name, HASH(Name) --How to achieve this?
FROM People
```

Comment: Why not create an index for the Name column instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `checksum()` (documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189788.aspx)) or `binary_checksum()`:

```
select name, checksum(name)
from people;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @HashThis nvarchar(max);
SET @HashThis = CONVERT(nvarchar(max),name);
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA1', @HashThis);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use system function that is already in sql server:- `sys.fn_repl_hash_binary`

```
SELECT Name, sys.fn_repl_hash_binary(cast(name as varbinary(max)))
FROM People
```